# Loading extensions in php5-fpm

Tags: php, nginx, zephir

I am in the process of experimenting with Zephir on my Nginx/php5-fpm/ubuntu14.04 setup.  I followed their tutorial and managed to compile my first Zephir PHP extension with little difficulty.  However, when I tried to enable the newly built extension by editing /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini to include

```
extension=/path/to/test.so
```

did not show up the *test* extension upon issuing php -m.  I then remembered that to install the mcrypt extension I use php5enmod mcrypt.  So I went to /etc/php5/mods-available and created the file test.ini

```
extension=/path/to/test.so
```

and then issued a

```
php5enmod test
```

A simple

```
service php5-fpm restart && php -m
```

later and lo & behold the test extension was present!  All very good but I still do not understand how php5enmod does its magic.  It clearly is not writing to the php.ini file.  I'd be much obliged to anyone who might be able to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php5enmod simply creates a symlink from the usual `conf.d` (for example: /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d) directoy to point to where the real files are in `mods-available`, prefixed with a number that indicates the priority (default: 20) of the module.

Answer (score 0):

I inadvertently ran `php5enmod` without `sudo`. The error messages is interesting:

```
rolf@two:/etc/php5$ php5enmod curl
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-curl.ini': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/php5/modules/fpm/disabled_by_maint/curl': Permission denied
```